# for loop for star pettern

Tags: java, for-loop

I am a beginner for coding.
I try to making star pattern as show below;

```
public class Exercise19
  {
  public static void main(String[] args)
     {
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
        for(int j = i; j < 5; j++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

I don't understand inner loop and outer loop because when i changed inner loop to be
(int j = 1; j < i; j++). It is different pattern.

Please explain about it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: to understand, instead of printing stars print the values of `i` & `j`

Comment: Outer loop counts from `1` to `4`. Inner loop counts from `i` to `4`, i.e. it iterates `4`, `3`, `2`, and then `1` times. When you change to `(int j = 1; j < i; j++)` it will count from `1` to `i - 1`, i.e. it iterates `0`, `1`, `2`, and then `3` times.

Answer (score 0):

The outer for loop keeps track of the line number. Or, in other words, it is used to count the number of lines we are printing. The inner for loop is used to keep track of the number of *'s we are printing.

For e.g
The number n is atken as an input from the user:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println(); 

}
```

Note that we have used the print() method and not the println() method to display the stars as we want the *'s to be displayed on the same line. And after the inner loop is executed, we go to the next line using the println() statement.

> If the input is five, the following pattern needs to be printed. 
>   *
>   ** 
>   *** 
>   **** 
>   *****